# Does an SD card over SPI need a level shifter?

Tags: spi, level-shifting, sd

I want to implement an SD card on my PCB. As I'm lacking a bit of experience. I bought a breakout board, which I could not get to work.
https://www.az-delivery.de/products/micro-sd-card-adapter-shield

Therefore, I bought another one with a level shifter: https://www.az-delivery.de/products/copy-of-spi-reader-micro-speicherkartenmodul-fur-arduino. This one worked perfectly.

To exclude that the first board had any hardware issues, I took an SD-card adapter and soldered some wires on it. It's ugly, but all contacts work fine. On the oscilloscope, the data packages are visible. This one also failed.

[image]

Now I'm asking if the level shifter is required to get the interface to work correctly? Is this the same issue as [SD card breakout board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/551248/sd-card-breakout-board)?

Comment: Whether or not you need a level shifter depends on what voltage you use on SD card and with what you want to interface it.

Comment: SD card is compatible with 3.3V. As long as you provide 3.3V for SD card power, you don't need level shifter.

Comment: I use 3.3V. What I do not understand, the signal on board with level shifter also is 3.3V.

Comment: And it has a step-down voltage regulator.

Comment: 1.8V is used for high speed low voltage standard. If you're doing some Arduino-like stuff, 3.3V will just work.

Comment: Ok seems that I still screw up something. In theory, my quick and dirty stuff should work as well?

Comment: @PCBCrewEngineer Actually you are wrong. Connecting 3.3V SD card to an 5V Arduino or 1.8V MCU would fry it. So there are cases where level shifting is needed, either up or down. And SD cards can use multiple voltages, not just 3.3V.